# Read one Firebase database entry once and return its value

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, asynchronous, es6-promise

I'm trying to get the data from a firebase db entry. The use case is as follows: I will query a web API with a latitude, longitude and radius which a query with the GeoQuery library, this library provides a database structure associated to a database entry key. I use the key_entered event manager to trigger all of the matching location database entries.

I now want to check whether the associated datas timestamp is newer than now but I got some struggles getting the data out of the Promise. I'm aware that the code below is not working due to the asynchronous nature of Promises, but is there any possibility to associate the data of once with a variable, e.g. waiting for the Promise to return something until continuing (like await etc.)?

I'm fully aware of the asynchron nature of node.js here but I have to return the data to the res.send since it provides an enclosed API call.

I also already used a callback function to call inside the db query promise and tried to associate it to data, that did not work as well.

```
function queryGeoLocation(req, res) {
try {
    const lat = parseFloat(req.params.lat);
    const long = parseFloat(req.params.long);
    const radius = parseFloat(req.params.radius);

    let geoQuery = geoFire.query({center: [lat, long], radius: radius});

    data = new QueryData(); //Use this to handle data asynchronously
    geoQuery.on("key_entered", (key, loc, dist) => {
        isFutureEvent = false;
        admin.database().ref("/events/").child(key).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
            if(Date.parse(snapshot.val().date) >= Date.now())
                isFutureEvent = true;
        }).catch(() => {
        });
        console.log(isFutureEvent);

        if (isFutureEvent){
            data.add(key, loc, dist);
        }
    });

    // When ready directly cancel the query provider and return data (since we only want to read once)
    geoQuery.on('ready', () => {
        geoQuery.cancel();
        res.send(data.getData());
    });
} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send("Error: " + err);
}
```

}

Comment: Really what you should do here is make queryGeoLocation return a promise that resolves with the data that the caller needs.  The caller than use that promise to react to the availability of data by using then() on that promise.

Comment: Yes that would be a great way for me. I wasn't aware of the fact that I can return a Promise in a http request. Is it possible to handle such a return by a XMLHttpRequest, which I am currently using on client side?

Comment: There is a node.js module called request-promise that returns a promise that resolves when an HTTP request is done: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

Comment: Unfortunately I do not fully get my head around it. What I want to do is to fetch multiple entries which are near the queried location and in my understanding I'm not able to handle this with a single Promise. Are there in addition any docs on how the Promise actually works, does it let the http connection open until data is exchanged and does request-promise take this into account or is it a simple promsification of http requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself by chaining Promises. Maybe a little overcomplicated but I'm working on it.

```
function queryGeoLocation(req, res) {
    try {
        const lat = parseFloat(req.params.lat);
        const long = parseFloat(req.params.long);
        const radius = parseFloat(req.params.radius);

        let geoQuery = geoFire.query({center: [lat, long], radius: radius});

        getGeoData = function(geoQuery) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                data = new QueryData();
                geoQuery.on("key_entered", (key, loc, dist) => {
                    data.add(key, loc, dist);
                });

                geoQuery.on('ready', () => {
                    geoQuery.cancel();
                    resolve(data.getData());
                });
            });
        };

        dbQuery = function (key) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                admin.database().ref("/events/").child(key).on('value', (data) => {
                    if (Date.parse(data.val().date) < Date.now())
                        resolve(false);
                    else
                        resolve(true);
                });
            });
        };

        checkIfDateIsNewer = function(geoData) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                for (let key in geoData){
                    if(geoData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        dbQuery(key).then((isNewer) => {
                            if (!isNewer)
                                delete geoData[key];
                        });
                    }
                }

                resolve(geoData);
            });
        };

        getGeoData(geoQuery).then(checkIfDateIsNewer).then(function(data) {
            res.send(data);
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send("Error: " + err);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send("Error: " + err);
    }
}
```